# How to send a row in table into struts action?

Tags: forms, struts2

I have displayed a table using struts iterator tag. Now every row has an edit link at the end. I need to be able to send that row into action when the edit button is clicked .

But I am unable to understand how to do that. I have

```jsp
<s:form action="/execute" id="frm" name="frm" method="POST">
    <table style="width: 800px; ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>        
                <th>Actions </th>      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <s:iterator value="listToIterate" var="row" status="stat" begin="0" >
            <tbody>    

                <tr>    
                    <td><s:property value="ID"  /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="Name"  /></td>               
                    <td><s:a href="#" onclick="document.forms['frm'].submit();">
                            edit<s:param name="Name" value="%{#row[2]}"/></s:a></td>        
                    </tr>       
                </tbody>    
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Using the param tag I want to set the row as a parameter so that I can retrieve it in my action . How do I do this ?

Comment: What do you want to set the row parameter to? The row index?

Comment: @bmorris591 yes, so that I can set the whole row as a parameter and get it in my action

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form is displaying id's correctly... then substitute your s:a with one following this form:

```
<s:a namespace="/yournamespace" action="the-edit-action">
   edit<s:param name="ID" value="ID"/>
</s:a>
```

I would rather ID be called id. the-edit-action will need a getter and setter for id.

Comment: this works but what I really want to do parameterize the whole row and get the whole row as a parameter in my action using an arraylist or string[]

Comment: I don't think you should do that, but if you want to look into Struts2 ModelDriven (can cause a lot of problems) or simply create a getter/setter for your your database entity such as get/setPerson and then just call the name fields person.id, person.name etc.